# How can I hide Registration and Login Using CSS in Mobile and Desktop?

Tags: css, wordpress

How can I hide Registration and Login Using CSS in Mobile and Desktop?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2i5cj.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

```
@media (max-width:1024) {
li.user_login.user_dashboard {
display: none;
}
```

You can use media queries and add properties to class to show.hide content

Comment: hi this is the link http://agency.spottedmagazine.co/Agency/ can u check if thats the right code?

Comment: Its not working it still shows registration and llogin in the main meni

Answer (score 0):

hi this is the link http://agency.spottedmagazine.co/Agency/ can u check if thats the right code?